# Dynamically positioning elements using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working om a menu bar, each menu bar item is an image, when user places mouse over menu item a div with submenu will appear.

I want to place div directly under the appropriate  image item (no space, and div will hover above all elements),  with right side alignment, meaning the right top corner of div should be under bottom right corner of image.

Because I can't and don't want to hard code position of divs, i want to do it dynamically.

For now I have this:

```
$('img').each(function(){                     
   jQuery(this).mouseenter(function(){
     var menuItem = $('#' + this.id + '_menu'); //get the needed div 
     var imgRight = this.offset() + this.width();


   });
 });
```

Comment: And what is your problem? You definitively have to use `$(this).offset()` and  `$(this).width()`.

Comment: I asked if there is something else I can use

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `offset()` method has `top` and `left` properties, you need use them, example:

```
var imgRight = this.offset().left + this.width();
var imgTop = this.offset().top + this.height();
```

After that, you will have to give the `absolute` positioning to the DIVs to place them below the images:

```
menuItem.css({
  position:'absolute',
  top: imgTop,
  left: imgLeft,
  zIndex:5000
});
```

So your code becomes:

```
$('img').each(function(){                     
   jQuery(this).mouseenter(function(){

   var menuItem = $('#' + this.id + '_menu'); //get the needed div 
   var imgRight = this.offset().left + this.width();
   var imgTop = this.offset().top + this.height();

     menuItem.css({
       position:'absolute',
       top: imgTop,
       left: imgLeft,
       zIndex:5000
     });

     // now show the corresponding div
     menuItem.show('slow');

   });
});
```

More Info:

http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Comment: and how to place div under the image? Do i need to calculate the position  or there is a better way?

Comment: @ilann: Yes you need them with a greater value, i have added that in my answer.

Comment: the left position of the div is not correct. the div's right border is not aligned with img's right

Comment: @@ilann:: You should post your working demo in something like jsbin.com for us to see.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to hard code or calculate the position of these items. Any of the following CSS rules should achieve your goal: `position: relative; right: 0` or `float: right:`.

It'd be good to see some of your markup for additional testing. [www.jsfiddle.net](http://www.jsfiddle.net) is a great resource for this.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do this: the correct-way or the cheat way...
The correct way: you need to get the top and client height of the actuating object - client heights no prob just call it - but the top means you must get the to of all the parent objects too - use this:

```
function J_pos(o)
{
    var x,y;
    y=o.offsetTop;
    x=o.offsetLeft;
    o=o.offsetParent;
    while(o)
    {
        y+=o.offsetTop;
        x+=o.offsetLeft;
        o=o.offsetParent;
    }
    return [x,y];
};
```

Now the top and client height you do this:

```
<div style=top:"+(p[0]+obj.clientHeight)+";left:"+p[1]>
```

The cheat-way (not so dynamic - but quick):
put a tag like a `<span>` around the actuating (mouseover) object. Make it position-relative. Place a `<div>` inside it:

```
<div id="ABC" style="position:absolute;left:0;display:none">
```

Now on mouseover put `document.getElementById("ABC").style.display=""` and `bottom:0` — boom baby dusted. Downside to this is you have to manually do it for each instance, but if you only have 3 or so well bingo.